# Oracle ADF Image Upload

Tags: image, oracle, upload, oracle-adf

I tried  all  the things 
 Oracle Fusion Developer Guide 11g  in working with oracle multimedia types
I am getting error in image upload with Oracle Multimedia Attributes....I am getting error in:

```
 <af:inputfile tag with

<binding:convertOrdDomain bindingRef="{bindings.Image}">
```

No namespace grammer defined ..help me in detail

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, including the actual error message you are getting.  What are you trying to do, what have you tried and what are you getting.  Be specific, we can't see your screen.

Comment: No grammar defined for the namespace .,I added adf face data binding to jsp tag libraries,still  the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the uploaded image in database or application server..? What approach you have tried, if you have some sample code, please post so that we can look into it.